# Does k6 browser support url matching patterns for thresholds?

Tags: grafana, k6, xk6-browser

Im currently trying to write some tests for web app within k6 experimental browser.

While I can create a threshold like this, that works just fine:

```
thresholds: {
‘webvital_largest_content_paint{url:www.example-url.com/somepage/someinneresource/page.html’ : [‘p(90) < 2500’],
},
```

Following threshold doesn’t seem to monitor trace:

```
thresholds: {
‘webvital_largest_content_paint{url:www.example-url.com/**’ : [‘p(90) < 2500’],
},
```

Is there some way to achieve this? It would be nice to be able to make some patterns for urls, like I log in to some certain page, but then id in the query string could be diffferent, so it would be more convenient to just use some general patterns like this.

Another thing is that k6 browser doesn’t seem to pick up urls for thresholds unless You use these urls in actions like await page.goto(url) or await page.reload(), are there any plans to maybe extend this thresholds measurments for redirects from page to page, without explicitly calling those page with page.goto or page.reload?

Comment: I don't think there is at the moment. You'd manually have to tag your requests. With plain k6 (not k6-browser), you'd use `http.url\`...\`` tag to group your URLs.